# Is there any Checksum like mechanism for JSON?

Tags: json, web-services, checksum

I need to upload large amount of JSON data to a webservice. Whats the best way to analyse that the server received the data correctly and all data is uploaded? Please let me know if anyone has any experience in this regards. Thanks.

Comment: JsonTextReader will be helpful in your case.

Comment: I think HTTP has some sort of integrity-checking mechanism built-in. All you need to do is make sure that the transfer did not give an error code.

Comment: @divyabharathi thanks for the comment. What the JsonTextReader does? I did searched for it but didnt find any substantial info on its working. All I could find is that its based on .net. My webservice is on php, so I think it wont of any help to me.

Comment: @WaleedKhan You put forward a very valid point. I dont think theres any other way to go about this. Thanks.

Comment: @WaleedKhan, HTTP is just a transport protocol. It has no integrity mechanisms per se. You can send arbitrary data.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out my project :
https://github.com/hidayetcolkusu?tab=repositories

Calculation:

```
ChecksumCalculator checksumCalculator = new ChecksumCalculator();

string json = @"{""Name"":""Hidayet Raşit"",""Surname"":""ÇÖLKUŞU""}";

ushort checksum = checksumCalculator.Calculate(json);
Result: 43460
```

Comparing:

```
ChecksumCalculator checksumCalculator = new ChecksumCalculator();

string json = @"{""Name"":""Hidayet Raşit"",""Surname"":""ÇÖLKUŞU""}";

bool result = checksumCalculator.Compare(json, 43460);
Resut:true
```

Or

```
ChecksumCalculator checksumCalculator = new ChecksumCalculator();

string json = @"{""Name"":""Hidayet Raşit"",""Surname"":""ÇÖLKUŞU"",""Checksum"":43460}"; 

bool result = checksumCalculator.Compare(json);
Result:true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate json's hash value like this:

```
var sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
byte[] buf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
byte[] hash= sha1.ComputeHash(buf, 0, buf.Length); 
var hashstr = System.BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: Might want to mention the language (isn't that C#?)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate **md5** to compare two json.

```
public static string CreateMD5(string json)
{
    // Use json string to calculate MD5 hash
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
        byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not creditable. JSON can be formatted in many ways. SHA, MD5, Adler etc are not subitable for comparing JSON data in general, because comparison is made at binary level. One white sign more and you will have completely different binary data in JSON string, but the same objects after parsing.